# Mathematics - Vectors

Tags: vectors

There are 2 vectors $p$ and $q$.
$p$ is perpendicular to $q$.
$||p||=2||q||$.
Find angle between the vectors ($p+q$) and ($p \times q$).

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about dot-products (or inner products) and cosines?

Comment: What is $p*q$ ?

Comment: @neha Is p*q the dot product of p and q or cross product?

Comment: $p*q$ can't be a dot product (yon can't have an angle between a vector and a scalar). If it's a cross product, then it kind of makes sense. Just compute the cosine through the dot product and use distributive law to arrive at $p^2$, $q^2$ and $pq$ terms which you know.

Comment: @orion Both p and q are vectors.

Comment: p*q is the cross product and please ignore all the dots in the question.basically they were full stops sorry.

Comment: yeah I'm looking for the angle between p+q and p X q.  Basically i prefer using the astrix as a mulltiplication sign.  Sorry again

Comment: @neha they are perpendicular.

Comment: yeah the vectors p and q are perpendicular so their dot product becomes 0 but the question is to find the angle between (p+q) and (p X q).

Comment: Compute $\cos\phi=(p+q)\cdot (p\times q)/(\sqrt{(p+q)^2}\sqrt{(p\times q)^2})$. Use distribution law and it's done.

Comment: @ neha no no the angle between p+q and p cross q is also 90 because p cross q is perpendicular to the plane in which p and q lie. And p+q lies in the plane of p and q.

Comment: @user258250 exactly, but I suggest the OP does the calculation on his own. The only way to learn.

Comment: yeah I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle between the vectors ($p+q$) and ($p \times q$) is $\pi/2$ since ($p+q$) is perpendicular to ($p \times q$). Unless there is some more information not shown in your question.